# Is there a best practice for the rule order of CSS preprocessors?

Tags: css, sass, stylus

Is there a general best practice for the order of rules in CSS preprocessors like Stylus or SASS?

Is it better to first add the rules for the different types of the same element and then afterwards add the children of that element:

```
header
   &.fooBar
      float left
   nav
      background-color #fff
```

Or is it better to first add the children and afterwards add the parent's classes etc. like this:

```
header       
   nav
      background-color #fff
   &.fooBar
      float left
```

Comment: Personally I would expect to first see the styles of the patent and the one of the children. Because otherwise I would first go through the list of all children to see how their parent might affect their styling.

Comment: Better in which way? Performance optimation? Clean code?

Comment: Better in any way but of course rather clean code than performance.

Comment: Maybe you should check [this website](https://sass-guidelin.es/).

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: How would I know it's opinion based, there might have been an official best practice guide ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't general best practice for such a thing.

What's really important is to make up your mind and be consistent. Create coding guidelines in your company. Make a list of rules and stick to it, so everybody knows what to expect.